# Is it possible to enable the 'required' option for Dialogflow Intent Parameters using Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, dialogflow-cx

I'm trying to create an intent with a 'required' parameter that will prompt a response once the parameter is not satisfied. Is this possible through Node.js? If yes, how could I execute this. Thank you!

Comment: Hello, Could you please share if the scenario that you would like to accomplish is this one when creating the agent? Meaning that when some required parameter is not supplied, the agent will keep asking until it has collected all required data from the end-user. [Example](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/intents-actions-parameters#required)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the scenario that I'm trying to build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set parameters as "required" using the Node.js client library:

For [Dialogflow ES](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs), when creating an [Intent](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/intents-overview) using the [createIntent](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/dialogflow/latest/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.Intents.html#createIntent1) method, set the [request](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/dialogflow/latest/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.ICreateIntentRequest.html).[intent](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/dialogflow/latest/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.IIntent.html).[parameters.mandatory](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/dialogflow/latest/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.Intent.IParameter.html) field to “true” for the parameter you want to be required.

For [Dialogflow CX](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs), when creating a [Page](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/page) using the [createPage](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/dialogflow-cx/latest/google.cloud.dialogflow.cx.v3.Pages.html#createPage1) method, set the [request](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/dialogflow-cx/latest/google.cloud.dialogflow.cx.v3.ICreatePageRequest.html).[page](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/dialogflow-cx/latest/google.cloud.dialogflow.cx.v3.IPage.html).[form](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/dialogflow-cx/latest/google.cloud.dialogflow.cx.v3.IForm.html).[parameters.required](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/dialogflow-cx/latest/google.cloud.dialogflow.cx.v3.Form.IParameter.html) to “true” for the parameter you want to be required.